# Why page doesn't go to the chat in Spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-websocket

I do my first project in Spring. I've a problem with the chat. I do my chat with spring websocket. But It doesn't work, but i haven't some mistake. I enter the nickname and click "start chat", then the page does not go to the chat. 
My code:

```
@Controller
public class ChatController {
@GetMapping("/index")
    @MessageMapping("/chat.sendMessage")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage sendMessage(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage) {
        return chatMessage;
    }

    @MessageMapping("/chat.addUser")
    @SendTo("/topic/public")
    public ChatMessage addUser(@Payload ChatMessage chatMessage,
                               SimpMessageHeaderAccessor headerAccessor) {
        // Add username in web socket session
        headerAccessor.getSessionAttributes().put("username", chatMessage.getSender());
        return chatMessage;
    }

}
```

And:

```
public class ChatMessage {

        private MessageType type;
        private String content;
        private String sender;

        public enum MessageType {
            CHAT,
            JOIN,
            LEAVE
        }

        public MessageType getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setType(MessageType type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

        public String getContent() {
            return content;
        }

        public void setContent(String content) {
            this.content = content;
        }

        public String getSender() {
            return sender;
        }

        public void setSender(String sender) {
            this.sender = sender;
        }
    }
```

All my code is here:https://gist.github.com/Lapka1002/58987dc92f60d38860653eafc0292641
I do my chat in index

Comment: Can you show your client code?

Comment: I haven't something like this

Comment: Don't you have HTML/JS? How do you use this endpoint?

Comment: I added it in an answer

Comment: Some more information would be helpful. Is the websocket handshake successful? Can you show you websocket config?

Comment: @lapka1002 you should edit your question and post it there. Answers are **only** for **answers**.

Comment: Why should anything happen? You don't even reference your JS.

Comment: This is not the all code, I sent only the part that relates  the chat

Comment: I adde link with my code